# Different color bar chart from eCharts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I was trying to create a different color bar. For Mon blue, Tue red, Wed green. Please help me how to write it. `Line itemStyle: {normal: {color: 'blue','red', 'green'}}`, did not work. 
The code comes from the echarts site.

```
 <html style="height: 100%">
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
       </head>
       <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
           <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/vendors/echarts/echarts.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
    var dom = document.getElementById("container");
    var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
    var app = {};
    option = null;
    option = {
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed']
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'value'
        },
        series: [{
            itemStyle: {normal: {color: 'blue'}},
            data: [120, 200, 150],
            type: 'bar'
        }]
    };
    ;
    if (option && typeof option === "object") {
        myChart.setOption(option, true);
    }
           </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
    var option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            {
                value: 120,
                itemStyle: {color: 'blue'},
            },
            {
                value: 200,
                itemStyle: {color: 'red'},
            },
            {
                value: 150,
                itemStyle: {color: 'green'},
            }
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    }],
    graph: {
        color: colorPalette
    }
};
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/vFK1qeMfMCXGx8Gdn1d8?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you point me to any good resource for learning this?

Comment: I think that good resource is documentation: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/api.html#echarts

Comment: @coudy.one How can I make this work for dynamic data. If the data has not fixed values.. Here it is fixed with 3 items. For my case, data is dynamic and varies from time to time..

Comment: @surazzarus I've added an example for loading dynamic data: https://plnkr.co/edit/e5Ob1xn4h8VydpGUl3Ax?p=preview When you click the "Render" button, then the chart reads the new data.

Comment: @coudy.one Is there a way to set the data points in the HTML and get the color and value from data-attributes in the HTML? If not for ECharts, do you know of any JS Charts that have this ability?

Comment: @coudy.one thanks for the documentation link! I was struggling with the Chinese version of the same: https://echarts.baidu.com/tutorial.html#5%20%E5%88%86%E9%92%9F%E4%B8%8A%E6%89%8B%20ECharts

Comment: How can I achieve this by using dataset? @coudy.one

Answer (score 10):

The top solution was not working for me. [From their documentation](https://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/doc-en.html#ItemStyle) is seems lineStyle now has two children elements you can leverage 'normal' and 'emphasis'.
I had to modify it like so to override the default colors:

```
    var option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            {
                value: 120,
                itemStyle: { normal: { color: 'blue' } },
            },
            {
                value: 200,
                itemStyle: { normal: { color: 'red' } },
            },
            {
                value: 150,
                itemStyle: { normal: { color: 'green' } },
            }
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    }],
    graph: {
        color: colorPalette
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution in June 2019 for needing different colors based on values: Create separate series for the different colors, and use a stacked chart. For example, I needed to create a graph with green bars for passing values and yellow bars for failing values. This was my implementation:

```
var data = {};
data.legendData = ['Sales','HR','Engineering'];
data.greenSeriesData = ['-',96.38,98.43];
data.yellowSeriesData = [44.23,'-','-'];

var option = {
    title: {
        text: '2019 Progress',
        left: 'center'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: data.legendData
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        axisLabel: {
            formatter: function (val) {
                return (val) + '%';
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: data.greenSeriesData,
        type: 'bar',
        stack: 'colorbyvalue',
        label: {
            show: true,
            position: 'insideTop',
            formatter: "{c}%",
            color: '#000000'
        },
        barWidth: 50,
        itemStyle: {
            color: 'green'
        }
    },
    {
        data: data.yellowSeriesData,
        type: 'bar',
        stack: 'colorbyvalue',
        label: {
            show: true,
            position: 'insideTop',
            formatter: "{c}%",
            color: '#000000'
        },
        barWidth: 50,
        itemStyle: {
            color: 'yellow'
        }
    }],
    animation: false
};
```

Answer (score 1):

After a day of research got this answer => add itemStyle with seriesIndex as params

```
var option = {
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed']
},
yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
},
series: [{
    data: [ 120,200,150],
    type: 'bar',
    itemStyle: {
      // HERE IS THE IMPORTANT PART
      color: (seriesIndex) => yourCustomFunctionName(seriesIndex) // you will get access to array data passed and its index values
     },
    }],
    graph: {
    color: colorPalette
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new `colorBy` option: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.colorBy

Usage:

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
        type: 'bar',
        colorBy: 'data' // <---
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have an array corresponding to the colors that you need for each day.

initially that could be empty and then you push the relevant color to it, depending on that day!

```
  var cars1 = data.data_1;

  var color_bar = [];

  var text = "";
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < cars1.length; i++)
    {
    if (cars1[i] < 20.35) {
        color_bar.push("red");
          }  
        else {
      color_bar.push("yellow");
    }

  }
```

and the you call the relevant color for each data series...

```
yAxis: {
              type: 'value'
          },
          series: [{
              data: 
              [
            {
                value: data.data_1[0],
                itemStyle: {color: color_bar[0]},
            },{
                value: data.data_1[1],
                itemStyle: {color: color_bar[1]},
            },{
                value: data.data_1[2],
                itemStyle: {color: color_bar[2]},
            }],
```

Here I worked out an example based on value, but conditioning "day" should be ok.

I hope this helps mate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to set color for each data that you got you can just pass this props inside series and echart will give you random different colors

```
 series: [
        {
            data: [120,200,350,70,18,150],
            colorBy: "data",
            type: 'bar',
            barWidth: "50%",
    ],
```

Just add this:

```
colorBy :'data'
```

Happy coding !!