# ECharts: dataset with bars colored based on category name?

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

I'd like to be able to control bar colors based on xAxis/category label name, throughout multiple charts, while using the `dataset.source` option of feeding data.

I'm guessing the solution might involve using [visualMap](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#visualMap)?

```
customColors = {
 x1: '#123',
 x2: '#456',
 x3: '#789',
 ...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think visualMap is the way to do this, you probably want to set the colors in series:
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.data.itemStyle.color 
or define a color palette:
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#color

Echarts should color the chart by series by default:
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.colorBy

Comment: `itemStyle.color` is the effect I'm trying to achieve, just that I'm piping the data via `dataset.source`, not through the axis.data / series.data option, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49172321/107671)

Comment: Try defining a color palette then ("color" option) or define a "color" attribute in dataset objects